# Send docker container logs on EC2 to CloudWatch

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, airbyte

I have deployed Airbyte in EC2 using the instructions [here](https://docs.airbyte.com/deploying-airbyte/on-aws-ec2)
My next goal is to send the logs to CloudWatch because I read somewhere that storing logs in EC2 has crashed the instance.

My EC2 details:

1. In a custom VPC
2. Private Subnet
3. IAM Role attached to get full access to CloudWatch Logs

Please advise!

I have tried the following :

- IAM role created and attached it to my EC2 instance.
- CloudWatch Log Group `airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer` has been created
- I have found out the command to configure the log group from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62707306/17178678)
- I did a `docker images -a` in my ec2, it returned all the images of airbyte services (airbyte/airbyte-api-server, airbyte/worker, airbyte/db etc)
- Now, Airbyte comes with a startup script to up all the Airbyte services using `./run-ab-platform.sh -b` which I have been using to start Airbyte

How do I configure the logs to a CloudWatch Log Group in my case?
It looks like the commands to do that are -

```
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/airbyte-api-server:0.50.30        
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/worker:0.50.30                    
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/webapp:0.50.30                   
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/temporal:0.50.30                 
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/server:0.50.30                    
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/proxy:0.50.30                    
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/db:0.50.30                       
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/connector-builder-server:0.50.30  
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/cron:0.50.30                      
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/init:0.50.30                      
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/bootloader:0.50.30                
docker run -it --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=airbyte-ec2-DockerContainer airbyte/source-mysql:3.0.8
```

But I haven't figured out where to run these commands since there already is a `./run-ab-platform.sh` script. How do I modify that script?